# Tungsten Wire Heat discipation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, electricity

Background Information:
I'm doing an experiment in which I place a bare tungsten wire in to various liqids, to measure a coefficient $\alpha $ in the equation 
$$ Power Dissipated = \alpha * \Delta T $$
I was also given the equation:
$$R=R_0*(1+0.0045 \Delta T)$$
I decided to measure $R_0$ at a low voltage and current to stop the wire from heating up. Then I placed it in the liquid and measured the current going through the wire for a variety of voltages.

Originally I planed the substitute $Power Dissipated = V*I$ and obtain $R$ from the tangent of a V-I graph (can't use Ohms Law because the situation isn't ohmic)
Unfortunately once I have substituted the values into the formulae I got a different value for every data point (all in the same range 10^-7).
It made me wonder is there an equivalent formula for non-ohmic power I'm missing or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Have you considered that the $\Delta T$ in your power equation is not the same as the $\Delta T$ in your resistance equation unless the initial temperature of the liquid and the temperature at which you measured $R_0$ are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pranav's comment neatly identifies the problem. The temperature of the wire and the fluid aren't the same, and you don't know the temperature of the wire.

You need to measure $V$ and $I$, then calculate $R$ and use the second equation to calculate the temperature of the wire. Assuming you have a thermometer in your liquid you can now calculate the $\Delta T$ to use in your first equation.